# I want to concat or add date from one column with time from another and result should be in datatime

Tags: sql-server, ssms

```sql
select convert(datetime,  FORMAT(Convert(datetime, '2022-08-27 01:00:00.000'),'yyyy:MM:dd')+' '+

 FORMAT(Convert(datetime, '2022-08-27 12:01:30.000'),'hh:mm:ss'))
```

error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: `yyyy:MM:dd` isn't a valid format for string to be converted to a `datetime` (either as an implicit conversion, or with a style code).

Comment: Considering that these are literal values too, why not just `CONVERT(datetime, '2022-08-27T12:01:30.000');`? What *aren't* you telling us here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert one side to `date` and the other to `time`, which will truncate them. Then convert them back to `datetime` (to avoid conversion problems) and add them together.

For example:

```sql
DECLARE @d1 datetime = '2022-08-27 01:00:00.000';
DECLARE @d2 datetime = '2022-08-27 12:01:30.000';

SELECT
  CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, @d1)) + CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(time, @d2));
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5197e9ad28490c5b1f14227b58b2bf7f)